# Finding the Length of a Bisector

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle having lengths $4\sqrt3$, $12$, and $8\sqrt3$. Find the length of the bisector of the second largest angle.

I know the answer is 8 but what is the process that leads to that answer?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using the cosine rule, or the converse of Pythagoras' theorem, what shape is the triangle?
2. Identify the second largest angle.
3. Use the angle bisector theorem to find the ratio in which the angle bisector divides the opposite side.
4. Use the cosine rule or Pythagoras' theorem to find the length of the angle bisector.